# Powershell robocopy logging

Tags: powershell

How can you log to a text file only new files that have been robocopied  from source to destination.  I've tried the robocopy /LOG:file command however that logs everything

Comment: By default, RoboCopy does _not_ copy files it deems identical, and such files do _not_ show in its logs _by name_ (only as part of the _stats_, in column "Skipped"). Please clarify your requirements, by directly updating your question (please don't respond in a _comment_).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ***Out-File*** function in powershell in order to output logs to text file instead of outputting them in the shell.

```bsh
$execution = #some robocopy function to run
$execution| Out-File -LiteralPath "your_path"
```

Comment: The OP's problem isn't that the output can't be saved to a file - they're already doing that with `robocopy`'s  `/LOG:file` parameter. Instead, the stated desire is that only files that _were actually copied_ (due to being newer in the sour dir. than in the target dir.) be logged.